# How to access my docker container without mentioning port using Host Nginx?

Tags: docker, nginx, webserver, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

Here is my Nginx.conf file

Error message

[image: 1]

Here is my nginx.conf file , also tried restart nginx,
But i can access container at this http://ipaddress:8888

```
    server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  _;
        #root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        proxy_pass http://18.215.189.243:8888/;
       }
        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
```

Comment: please run `curl -I http://ipaddress` and `curl -I http://ipaddress:8888` then share the output.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue resolved,
the main problem was that I was using Nginx configuration in my host machine and uploading my code to the Nginx container.

I uninstalled nginx form my host machine and just using nginx container  and it is working fine